# Multip Choice Question - Postgres Join two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL previously we were using MongoDB and now we have shifted to Postgres. basically, we have 2 tables of Questions and Options. Each question can have multiple option so I design the database just like below table.

Table : dialogues

| dialogue_id | dialogue_text | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |

Table : options

| option_id | option_name | dialogue_id ( which is FK for table question) |
| --- | --- | --- |

Now I am trying to get all the questions with their options. I have tried inner join like this

```
SELECT options.option_name, dialogues.*
FROM options INNER JOIN dialogues ON dialogues.dialogue_id = options.dialogue_id)
```

But it's not what I wanted.

Just to give you an example in Mongo we have used this query

```
const aggregateQuery = [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "options", // The collection you want to join to
            localField: "_id", // The field in orders you want to join on
            foreignField: "question_id", // The field in products you want to join on
            as: "options" // What you want to call the array that stores the joined documents from products
          }
        },
     
    
        }
      ]
      const questionList = await questionModel.aggregate(aggregateQuery)
```

In result I wanted all the dialogue along with field called "options" which contains all the relevant options from table "options".
let me share the final JSON that I get from mongo.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "yyyyy",
            "question": "What is your gender?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "_id": "xxxxx",
                    "option": "Male",
                    "question_id": "yyyyy",
                    "created_at": "2020-07-04T05:57:00.293Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-07-04T05:57:00.293Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "xxxx",
                    "option": "Female",
                    "question_id": "yyyyy",
                    "created_at": "2020-07-04T05:57:00.293Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-07-04T05:57:00.293Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

can anybody help ?

Comment: in the table options you do not show us field dialogue_id. Please provide sample data nd desired output

Comment: I want an array of all questions with options as an array in each row. I hope that suffiecent

Comment: Sample data that is requested should look like (i.e.) this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ecf7d0078842a22ade6bd25f90615913)    (Note: I know information is missing in this dbfiddle, but you are allowed to improve the example )    **Currently it is still unclear what "But it's not what I wanted." does mean!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your solution.

```sql
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) from
(
 select 
   d.dialogue_id "_id", 
   d.dialogue_text "question",  
   ( 
     select 
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('_id', o.option_id, 'option', o.option_name))
       from options o
       where o.dialogue_id = d.dialogue_id
   ) "options"
 from dialogues d
) t;
```

Here is a JOIN/GROUP BY version

```
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) from
(
 select 
   d.dialogue_id "_id", 
   d.dialogue_text "question",  
   jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('_id', o.option_id, 'option', o.option_name)) "options"
 from dialogues d inner join options o using (option_id)
 group by d.dialogue_id, d.dialogue_text
) t;
```

Comment: let me try that out.

Comment: see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0adc8bb78f21ab6cf3e9f040ccede350) 

Comment: wow!! thanks @Luuk and Thanks Stefanov.sm